# SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

How do I feel the essentialness of SwingUtilities.invokeLater() in any swing application.Please give some code example.

Comment: See also "Continuations as objects": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style#Continuations_as_objects

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you need to update something inside your GUI you should do it through the **AWT Event Thread**.

This because AWT (and Swing on top) has its own thread that manages everything of a GUI. Without it the graphical interface couldn't handle events and similar things in an asynchronous way while your program is doing something else.

So for example if you have a long task declared in a `Thread`:

```
public void MyThread extends Thread
{
  class GUIUpdate implements Runnable
  {
    GUIUpdate(String msg)
    {
      ...
    }

    public void run()
    {
      guiElement.appendText(msg);
    }
  }

  public void run()
  {
     while (finished)
     {
        //do long calculations

        //send partial output to gui
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GUIUpdate("something has changed!"));
     }
   }
 }
```